# C prog that generates/output 3 numbers (any combination from 1 - 20) when added is equal to 20

Tags: c, function, logic

C prog that generates/output 3 numbers (any combination from 1 - 20) when added is equal to 20. Hope you could help me with this one. Thanks in advance.

```
int main(){ 
    int num1,num2,num3,sum; 

    do{ 
        printf("%i+%i+%i=%i\n",num1,num2,num3,sum); 
    } while(sum=20); getch(); 
}
```

Comment: Show your effort please (what you have tried so far)?

Comment: **What...** oh, we are tired from repeating this... **What have you tried?**

Comment: Anyway, that is not programming question, it's more logic (combinatoric). So if you don't have any logic, why do you learn programming?

Comment: `
    main(){
     int num1,num2,num3,sum;
 
     do{
      printf("%i+%i+%i=%i\n",num1,num2,num3,sum);
 
     }
     while(sum=20);
    getch();
 
    }` Lol that's all Ive got :)

Comment: This is mostly a combinatorics problem. The programming part is largely incidental. Tell us about your algorithm. Don't just post code with no explanation of how it is designed.

Comment: Now this question should be reopen.

Comment: A simple method you can use: `#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n1,n2;
    srand(time(NULL));
   
        n1 = 1 + rand() % 18;
     n2 = 1 + rand() % (19 - n1);
     if(n2 > 1)
     n2--;
     printf("%d %d %d\n", n1, n2, 20 - (n1+n2));

    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. You should be able to modify it according to your needs.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=1;i<=20;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=20;j++)
            for(k=1;k<=20;k++)
                if(i+j+k==20)
                    printf("%d %d %d\n",i,j,k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: too much time consuming.

Comment: Lol! I dont have to edit anything from your code! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Diptesh I know this was just a brute force method and Since it is his home work kind of stuff I cant be thinking of an ***Optimized*** algorithm.

Comment: agree with you vivek1794

Comment: How you answered after this question has been closed? o__O

Comment: @ray Don't forget to give vivek credit when you turn in the assignment.

Comment: @haccks it was more like I answered the question and the next second this question was closed. I think I wont be able to answer once the question is closed right?

Comment: Once question is closed you can't answer it. You posted your answer after 3 minutes of the question being closed.

Comment: I am not sure about that @haccks.. The answer this question was available for me so I just clicked and answered.. Not sure if I did something wrong here.. If it is, then I am sorry :) can delete the answer if its out of rule or something